# How to make restart python program button using tkinter button

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, button

im try to make restart button for my python program gui [My gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDd97.jpg) but im still confused how to do it. Anyone know how to  make the button to restart python code ? I appreciate every help.

Comment: Depends on how you designed your program. Can you give us a [mre] of your program?

Comment: im making python gui with tkinter and i want have button to restart the program

Comment: That doesn't help. Are you using classes? Do you have a main function? How many `tk.Tk` windows do you have? Do you have any global variables that you need to reset? Can you just close the `tk.Tk` windows and call your main function? There are a lot of things that can change the solution, that is why on stackoverflow we ask for a [mre] so that we can see exactly how to approach your question.

Comment: i only have 1 tk and one button for my classfication program using defselectimage() and i want to add button to restart my program

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```py
import sys
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def restart_me():
    pth = sys.executable
    os.execl(pth, pth, *sys.argv)

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="hi there!").pack()
Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_me).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation? Code only answers aren't as helpful.

Comment: im getting error errno 2 no such file and directory

Comment: move you project to root of a drive like d:/ . also remove any space from your projects folder names and file name. then run it again